# Perforce - how to check how often developers update local code from server?

Tags: perforce

Some developers don't want to update used code often because some other developers commit bad code.

With Perforce (server or client tool) **how to check how often developers update local code from server?**

to discover what developers update from repo often and who updates rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in a single command, but you can put the pieces together into a tool if you wish.

Here are two different approaches:

Either examine your server log regularly, looking for log lines indicating that the 'user-sync' command was run, and analyze which workspace is running 'user-sync' at which time,

Or else you could:

1. Run 'p4 clients' to get a list of all the workspaces your developers are using.
2. For each client, run 'p4 -H host -C client sync -n' to see how many files they have not yet sync'd.
3. Examine these lists and draw your conclusions

Note that you should make these analyses over a period of time, because each individual workspace may fall behind, then catch up, in a different pattern.

Comment: Thanks, of course it is in logs. But implementing this tool ourselves would be overkill.